# How can I compile a Labview CIN in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, labview, cin

I am trying to compile a labview CIN using visual studio 2003.

I have followed the tutorial located [here](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/3172) to the letter, but am getting the following error:

> Project : error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing Custom Build Step"

Does anyone know what is causing this? I tried this [link](http://detritus.blogs.com/lycangeek/2006/03/building_cins_w.html) found at an expert's exchange [question](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/.NET/Visual_CPP/Q_23144843.html) but it does not seem relevant.

Is there an easier way to build a CIN using visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it.

Turns out it's an issue with the lsvbutil.exe bundled with labview 8.5. Workaround is to replace with the version from 8.2

See http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/0029165B53320B2886257369005826A1

Answer (score 0):

Please post the entire error.  It appears that the custom build step defined in your link does not work.

On the Custom Build Step->General page, type:

```
"$(CINTOOLS_DIR)\lvsbutil" "$(TargetName)" -d "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)"
```

in the commandline field and type `$(OutDir)$(TargetName).lsb` in the output field.

Try pasting that into a commandline and running it. I suspect you have not got the env variables set or they are not pointing to the right places.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out it was an issue with the version of lsvbutil.exe I had.